# How do I toggle tab z-indexes for shadow effect?

Tags: jquery, tabs, z-index, shadow

I'm new to a lot of this stuff and building a site with `Foundation 5`. My pic describes what I'm looking to do. I have 3 tabs with shadows and I lose the shadows depending on which tab is clicked. I'm not sure if this is achievable through `CSS` or `js/jquery`. Can I re-arrange the z-index of the tabs based upon which one is currently open?

this is it;

[image: https://s2.postimg.org/gpw3nrind/tabs.jpg]

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab data-options="deep_linking: true" scroll_to_content:"false">
    <li class="tab-title title1"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title title2"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li> 
    <li class="tab-title title3"><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>          

 <div class="tabs-content"> 
    <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
----stuff in this tab------</div>


<div class="content" id="panel2-2">
----stuff in this tab------</div>

<div class="content" id="panel2-3">
 ----stuff in this tab------</div>

div#all_tabs .tabs a{
min-width: 198px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
box-shadow:9px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
position: relative;

}

.tab-title.active{
  z-index: 98;
  position: relative;
}
.tab-title1{
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.title2{
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.title3{
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

div#all_tabs .tabs-content{
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
max-width: 952px;
min-height: 883px;
padding-top: 50px;
box-shadow:9px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a working jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/edohqw5j/8/